# How to calculate $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)\delta(x^2+\alpha^2) dx?$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

If $~\alpha\in\mathbb{R},$ $~~\delta~~$ is the Dirac's delta function. Then how to  calculate $$\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)\delta(x^2+\alpha^2) dx?$$

Comment: $0$ if $\alpha \ne 0$. This is because in that case, $x^2 + \alpha^2 \ne 0$ for all $x$.

Comment: I am not sure of your answer when $\alpha=0$. I agree with your answer for $\alpha \ne 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that Dirac's function is a snapshot function. If $f$ is continuous then $\delta$ will take a snapshot of $f$ when the argument of $\delta$ is zero.

So if $\alpha \ne 0$ then as achille hui pointed out, the argument to $\delta$ can never be zero.

If $\alpha=0$ then all bets are off. You have
$$
\int f(x) \delta(x^2) dx = f(0) \int \delta(x^2) dx
$$
The general result is
$$
\delta(g(x)) = \sum _i \frac{\delta(x-x_i)}{|g'(x_i)|} $$
where $x_i$ are the roots of $g(x)$. Now $g(x)=x^2$ and the root is $x=0$ and $g'(0) = 0$.
So the integral is $f(0) \times \infty$ which is undefined if $f(0) =0$.

Comment: Tks @user44197, moreover, i want to calculate $$ \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)\delta(x^4+(\alpha-x)^4-(\alpha-\alpha_1)^4-\alpha_1^4)dx,$$ where $\alpha$ and $\alpha_1$ indenpent of $x.$ can you give me some suggetions?

Comment: Same idea. Let $g(x) = x^4+(\alpha-x)^4-(\alpha-\alpha_1)^4-\alpha_1^4$. It should have four roots. Note that $g(x)=$$2\,\left(x-\alpha_1\right)\,\left(x+\alpha_1-\alpha\right)\,\left(x^2-
 \alpha\,x+\alpha_1^2-\alpha\,\alpha_1+2\,\alpha^2\right)$. The quadratic has discriminant $<0$ so the roots are distinct. I have edited my answer to include distinct roots.

Comment: So what would you say is $\int 2x \delta(x^2) dx$?

Comment: I would say depends! The substitution $u=x^2$ gives $\int \delta(u) du$. The problem is the limits are from $0$ to $\infty$. If the limit is $0^+$ then the integral is zero. If the limit is $0^-$ the integral is 1. It is customary to make the integral $1/2$ but I am not sure if this universally accepted.

Comment: @WinC. $\int 2x\delta(x^2)\mathrm dx$ looks like an meaningful expression, however such expression is not solved by the theory of distributions *stricto sensu* because $2x$ is not a test function. Rigorously you can say that $\int \varphi(x)\delta(x^2)\mathrm dx=\varphi'(0)/2$ if $\varphi(0)=0$ under the assumption that $\varphi$ is a test function.